# Mostrar div apenas após checar 3 radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver.

Preciso que uma div seja mostrada APENAS após 3 radio buttons forem checados, mas não está funcionando. Eu só estou conseguindo com uma opção só, mas tem que ser os 3 de uma vez e só depois de marcar os 3 é que tem que aparecer a div.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.control').on('click', function(){
        var n1 = $('#profissional-nao:checked');
        var n2 = $('#institucionalizada-nao:checked');
        var n3 = $('#indigena-nao:checked');

        if(n1.length > 0 && n2.length > 0 && n3.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="">
    Profissional de Saúde: <br>
    <input id="profissional-sim" name="{$q2_name}" type="radio" value="Sim" checked="" class="form-control"> Sim
    <input id="profissional-nao" name="{$q2_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="">
    Pessoa Institucionalizada?: <br>
    <input id="institucionalizada-sim" name="{$q3_name}" type="radio" checked="" value="Sim" class="form-control"> Sim
    <input id="institucionalizada-nao" name="{$q3_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="argem">
    Poulação Indigena ou em Terras Demarcadas?: <br>
    <input id="indigena-sim" name="{$q4_name}" type="radio" value="Sim" checked="" class="form-control"> Sim
    <input id="indigena-nao" name="{$q4_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="col-xs-12" id="fase-dois" style="display: none;">teste</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única alteração que precisei fazer no seu código para que ele funcione foi alterar o *binding*  do *event handler* `click` para trabalhar com a classe `form-control` (e assim tratar cliques de todos os *radio buttons*):

```js
$(function() {
    $('.form-control').on('click', function(){
        var n1 = $('#profissional-nao:checked');
        var n2 = $('#institucionalizada-nao:checked');
        var n3 = $('#indigena-nao:checked');

        if(n1.length > 0 && n2.length > 0 && n3.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
});
```

[**Veja funcionando no JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/vwueya63/).

É importante escutar por eventos de *click* em todos os *radio buttons* para esconder a `div` caso alguma opção seja trocada de *Não* para *Sim*.

Comment: Obrigada!! Funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

Como mencionado por @anthony-accioly você precisa escutar o clique de todos os inputs para reavaliar a cada clique deles.

Passos:

- Dá para fazer isso, por exemplo, adicionado a classe `.control` também aos inputs 'sim'
- Separar em funções para não ficar repetitivo
- Avaliar ao carregar da página se deve mostrar ou não (opcional)

[Link para codepen](https://codepen.io/emerson-pereira/pen/yLaGXVE?editors=1010)

```js
$(function() {
    function isAllChecked () {
        // jQuery retorna um array com o element em si no index 0 (primeira posição)
        // Abaixo é array destructure para captar o primeiro item do array
        var [input1] = $('#profissional-nao');
        var [input2] = $('#institucionalizada-nao');
        var [input3] = $('#indigena-nao');

        // Checka se todos (e somente se todos) os inputs do array estão checked
        // Se sim, retorna true, se um ou mais não estiver, retorna false 
        return [input1, input2, input3].every(
            (input) => input.checked
        );
    }
    
    // Elemento a ser mostrado / escondido
    var element = $("#fase-dois");

    // Checar se todos estão marcados nao a cada clique
    // e mostrar / esconder elemento a partir da resposta de isAllChecked()
    $('.control').on('click', function() {
        // Usar método toggle passando true ou false
        // sendo true mostra o elemento e vice-versa
        element.toggle(isAllChecked());
    });

    // Opcional: Checar se já está marcado tudo em nao ao carregar a página
    // e mostrar a div caso positivo
    $(document).ready(function() {
        element.toggle(isAllChecked());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
    Profissional de Saúde: <br>
    <input id="profissional-sim" name="{$q2_name}" type="radio" value="Sim" checked="" class="form-control control"> Sim
    <input id="profissional-nao" name="{$q2_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="">
    Pessoa Institucionalizada?: <br>
    <input id="institucionalizada-sim" name="{$q3_name}" type="radio" checked="" value="Sim" class="form-control control"> Sim
    <input id="institucionalizada-nao" name="{$q3_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="argem">
    Poulação Indigena ou em Terras Demarcadas?: <br>
    <input id="indigena-sim" name="{$q4_name}" type="radio" value="Sim" checked="" class="form-control control"> Sim
    <input id="indigena-nao" name="{$q4_name}" type="radio" value="Não" class="form-control control"> Não
</div>

<div class=""><br><br></div>

<div class="col-xs-12" id="fase-dois" style="display: none;">teste</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode modificar seu código de modo que o `if` fique da seguinte forma:

```
if(document.getElementById('id-radio-1').checked && document.getElementById('id-radio-2').checked && document.getElementById('id-radio-3').checked){
      document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'block';
}else{
      document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Lembrando que precisa modificar também o HTML para que os id's correspondam.

Comment: Obrigada pela sua respostas, mas ainda não tá funcionando. Devo estar fazendo algo errado.

$(function() {

    $('.control').on('click', function(){

     
        if(document.getElementById('profissional-nao').checked && document.getElementById('institucionalizada-nao').checked && document.getElementById('indigena-nao').checked){
         document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'block';
  }else{
        document.getElementById("fase-dois").style.display = 'none';
  };
    });
});